# Craft is unable to transfer your license to this domain at this time

Tags: license

We have a Craft Pro (Craft CMS 2.6.3004) website that has a number of aliases on the URL. For the purpose of this the main URL is awesome.zone which has an alias of myawesomesite.com.

Recently it has started showing the "The license location at config/license.key belongs to myawesomesite.com" when logged into the admin panel of awesome.zone.

[image]

Evidently it was registered on the Alias initially, so I went to transfer the domain, but Craft won't do it.

> Craft is unable to transfer your license to this domain at this time.

What's changed recently that my license is suddenly complaining (but has been fine for 2 years) and how do I fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the launch of [Craft ID](https://craftcms.com/news/introducing-craft-id), you can no longer transfer a license to a new domain directly from a Craft installation.  You can create a Craft ID account and from there, you can manage all of your Craft licenses, orders and download order receipts for previous orders.

This will also allow you to transfer the licenses that you own to other domains.

Comment: Hi Brad. The "Transfer license to this domain" button should probably be removed then. I'm not sure how this is going to work for us in terms of associating existing Craft licenses with the new Craft ID account. I'll set up an account and give it a go.

Comment: It is removed it you're running the latest Craft 2 version.